# Child windows not getting focus in Windows 7?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

I have a Win Forms application from which I can open child windows and sometimes also childrens' child windows. When I run the app in Windows XP, everything works ok but when I run it in Windows 7, most of the times child windows don't get the focus. Why?

Thanks

Comment: Try showing a small snippet of code that reproduces that.  It doesn't normally happen that way.

Comment: It's too complicated because I'm also using some pre-made components. My theory is that Win7 mixes up the order in which windows are opened but I can't figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!** For some reason, **Windows Aero** made this happen. My code (obviously) somehow conflicts with it, so when I switched Aero off (i.e. chose a Basic theme) everything started working fine and even faster than it used to.

Comment: You should marked this as the answer so others will know that this question is resolved.